# How to convert float value from array to corresponding chronos time for comparison

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, mbed

I'm working on a project that takes midi files and plays them out to stepper motors. I am using mbed os6 which uses chronos for all time based comparisons. I have an array of when the notes should start in seconds but I am not sure how to compare this to the current time given by

`std::chrono::duration<double> timerus = motor1timer.elapsed_time()`

Where elapsed time returns a chrono value in microseconds

I want the note to start playing after the current time exceeds the note start time preset in the array but I am quite rusty with c++ and don't know how to convert my float values to a chrono duration that I could use for logic comparisons. How would I go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Converting a float number_of_seconds value to a `chrono` duration looks like this:

```
double number_of_seconds = ...;
auto d = std::chrono::duration<double>(number_of_seconds);
```

if you were converting from a number of microseconds, you'd want:

```
double number_of_microseconds = ...;
auto d = std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro>(number_of_microseconds);
```